# CSS media queries, its not changing the properties from 1024 to 768

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using media queries and it should change color in 1024 view and 768 view but 768 media queries  inheriting  the properties from 1024.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .cashBalance  {
    font-size: 50px !important; 
    color: green !important;
    margin-left: -20px !important;
  } 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .cashBalance  {
    font-size: 65px; 
    color: red !important;
  }
 }
```

I am attaching the code pen link.
https://codepen.io/SahilKatia/pen/ejqjjJ

Comment: Try adding return false; whether it helps if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();  return false;
    }

Comment: add or operator with boolean @HostListener('touchend', ['$event']) onTouchEnd(event: Event): void | boolean {

Comment: Here is the stackoverflow link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipckpj

Comment: Anything that has `max-width: 768px` also has `max-width: 1024px` (and it would also have `max-width: 100000000px`), so your second rule overrides the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of the mediaqueries, now you are saying that in 1024 the color is green but since it is greater than 768 it is ignoring the other attribut

Comment: it works for me but I didn't understand how changing the order will solve my problem

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/ . check #Overriding